# Disable "shared terminal" behavior with Ubuntu 11.10 on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-11.10

I recently created by first EC2 server using an Ubuntu 11.10 AMI (previously had been using 10.4). The default terminal behavior for this server seems a bit odd.

When I ssh to the server from a Mac terminal window, and then ssh to the server again from a second Mac terminal window, both terminals share a session. E.g. the windows start mirroring each other - what I type in one shows up in the other. This isn't what I want. I want separate sessions (so that, for example, I could tail example1.log in one window and example2.log in another window).

I also see this behavior if I login to the server once on my Mac, and a second time from a different Mac (e.g. it's definitely a server-side behavior, not something batty about my laptop).

Anybody know how to disable this behavior and go back to separate terminal sessions?

Comment: +1 This is the single most stupid preset I have ever seen for a multi-user system! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time you log in to the instance, enter this command:

```
byobu-disable
```

This will log you out and future logins will not be forced to share.

You can also learn to use `screen` if you want to use its advanced functionality, but the above is the easy way to get back to a sane default.

Comment: Ah, god bless you. Order hath been restored to my universe.